# Content Control and Button Flyout

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am making a UWP app and I have come across a problem. I want to make a `StackPanel` which hosts two `ComboBoxes` and one `TextBox`. I can show it in the app if I create it inside the `Grid` and it works as expected. But for smaller screen devices I want to show a `Button` in place of the `StackPanel` and move the `StackPanel` to the button `flyout`.

I have tried to add the `StackPanel` to a `ContentControl` and then set it as the `Flyout` but it doesn't work. `Flyout` needs a `FlyoutPresenter` control to be able to show the flyout.

I don't want to create multiple `StackPanel` controls because of the naming collisions, but I do want it simple so I need to make changes to one side of the controls and when the user switches the screen or the view the smaller screen also shows the same stuff.

Can someone help me here? Maybe just point me in the right direction so I can figure it out on my own. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

`StackPanel` control:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                x:Name="PageOptionsPanel"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <AppBarButton Label="Refresh"
                    Icon="Refresh"
                    Tapped="PageOptions_Tapped"/>
            <RelativePanel Margin="10,0">
                <TextBlock Text="Sort by:"
                        Name="SortText"
                        RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"
                        Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                <ComboBox RelativePanel.RightOf="SortText"
                        x:Name="MSortingBox"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding EnSortList}"
                        RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"
                        SelectionChanged="MSortingBox_SelectionChanged"
                        Width="120"/>
            </RelativePanel>
            <RelativePanel Margin="10,0">
                <TextBlock Text="Country: "
                        Name="CountryText"
                        RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"
                        Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                <ComboBox RelativePanel.RightOf="CountryText"
                        x:Name="MCountryBox"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding EnCountryList}"
                        RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"
                        SelectionChanged="MCountryBox_SelectionChanged"
                        Width="120"/>
            </RelativePanel>
        </StackPanel>
```

`Flyout` control:

```
    <Button>
        <Button.Flyout>
            <Flyout Placement="Left"
                    x:Name="MOptionsFlyout"
                    Content="{StaticResource PageOptionsFlyout}"
                    Opened="MOptionsFlyout_Opened">
            </Flyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to share the XAML for your Options layout between the main page and a flyout, based on the size of the page (for phone vs tablet). You can do this by creating a DataTemplate with the layout and adding it to the page's resource dictionary. Then it can be referenced in multiple places.

Here's the code below that does that. It also hides and shows the pieces based on adaptive triggers.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PageOptionsTemplate">
        <StackPanel 
                    x:Name="PageOptionsPanel"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Orientation="Vertical">
            <AppBarButton
                        Icon="Refresh"
                        Label="Refresh" />
            <RelativePanel Margin="10,0">
                <TextBlock
                            Name="SortText"
                            Margin="0,0,5,0"
                            RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"
                            Text="Sort by:" />
                <ComboBox
                            x:Name="MSortingBox"
                            Width="120"
                            RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"
                            RelativePanel.RightOf="SortText"/>
            </RelativePanel>
            <RelativePanel Margin="10,0">
                <TextBlock
                            Name="CountryText"
                            Margin="0,0,5,0"
                            RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"
                            Text="Country: " />
                <ComboBox
                            x:Name="MCountryBox"
                            Width="120"
                            RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"
                            RelativePanel.RightOf="CountryText"
                             />
            </RelativePanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Name="OptionsFlyoutButton" Content="Show Me" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <Button.Flyout>
            <Flyout>
                <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource PageOptionsTemplate}"/>
            </Flyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
    </Button>
    <ContentControl Name="OptionsInLine" Visibility="Visible" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource PageOptionsTemplate}" />

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="320"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="OptionsInLine.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Setter Target="OptionsFlyoutButton.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1024"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>
```

You can also move the DataTemplate out to the application level ResourceDictionary, so that it can be shared between multiple pages.

Finally, another option is to create a user control (using the uwp item template) for this. I recommend creating that if you needed more control over the layout, wanted to encapsulate the logic too, and share it across multiple apps.

For your example, the shared DataTemplate is the easiest path.

Comment: Yes, Thank you for your answer. I already figured it out and it is the correct way as I did it the same way.

Comment: Great, glad that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
<Button Content="Show Me">
        <Button.Flyout>
            <Flyout>
                <StackPanel
                    x:Name="PageOptionsPanel"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Orientation="Vertical">
                    <AppBarButton
                        Icon="Refresh"
                        Label="Refresh" />
                    <RelativePanel Margin="10,0">
                        <TextBlock
                            Name="SortText"
                            Margin="0,0,5,0"
                            RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"
                            Text="Sort by:" />
                        <ComboBox
                            x:Name="MSortingBox"
                            Width="120"
                            RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"
                            RelativePanel.RightOf="SortText"/>
                    </RelativePanel>
                    <RelativePanel Margin="10,0">
                        <TextBlock
                            Name="CountryText"
                            Margin="0,0,5,0"
                            RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"
                            Text="Country: " />
                        <ComboBox
                            x:Name="MCountryBox"
                            Width="120"
                            RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"
                            RelativePanel.RightOf="CountryText"
                             />
                    </RelativePanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Flyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
    </Button>
```

to get this:
[image]

When using the  you get an auto display flyout that is shown whenever a user clicks the button, no code needed.

but to add content to that flyout, you need to have another  element in it, then the stackpanel goes into it.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Unfortunately you didn't understand my question, I can generate the flyout but I need this flyout also as a different control so I can show it elsewhere. Actually I want one `stackpanel` to be able to go into the flyout and out of the flyout and work as if it were the same control.